# Android Kotlin onItemSelectedListener for spinner not working

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner with some items (strings).
I want to add the selected items to a list. I read online that I should use the `onItemSelectedListener`rather than the `onItemClickListener`.

I implemented this but I don't know how to complete the step of adding it to the list.

```
class NewKitListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")
//var spinnerArray = arrayOf(DataService.kitList)



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_kit_list)



    val spinner = newKitItemSpinner
    val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)
    //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter

    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            if (selectedItem == "Add new category") {
                // do your stuff
            }
        } // to close the onItemSelected

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

        }
    }}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Create a new MutableList and add your item to this list.

Comment: @just, could you write an example of how I can pass it to the mutable list? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 144):

(in Kotlin)Use this code:

```
yourSpinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 25):

Thanks this is helpful for me, Its working fine !

```
daysSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: The code is useful to get the Int derived from choosing one item from the Spinner, if nothing selected it will get 0 because spinner starts in zero position.

Answer (score 4):

**Add extension function**

```
fun Spinner.selected(action: (position:Int) -> Unit) {
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            action(position)
        }
    }
}
```

**simple use**

```
spinner.selected {
    println(it) //selected position
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. How we can get position at selected{ }

Comment: @HarmanKhera update! Cheer!)

Answer (score 2):

string will not be able to check using '==' instead you need to use equals("string")

```
if (selectedItem.equals("Add new category")) {
            // do your stuff
        }
```

Comment: You are supposed to use `==` when comparing `Strings` in Kotlin

Comment: only in java not kotlin

Answer (score 1):

I implemented like this.
1. Create Empty Mutable List
2. Set onItemSelectedListner on spinner
3. When user select item add that to mutable list

Check my this answer for more info. It will help you: [Android Koltin pass spinner values to mutable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450622/android-koltin-pass-spinner-values-to-mutable-list)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")
```

try

```
var spinnerArray = mutableListOf<String>("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")
```

just had the same situation when I was trying to get a sqlite table´s $_ID and populate the spinner with them

Answer (score 0):

```
// Extends AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
class Dialogs : DialogFragment(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {}

//Somewhre in onCreate (I'm using databinding but you don't have to)
 binding.spinnerDialogEstados.onItemSelectedListener = this

// then implement members...

      override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34654690)