# How to create a spinner with different colors in each row

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to create a sppiner with different colors in each row, I know that there are many explanations similar to my question but they are all in Java and it has been complicated for me, I carry out the steps.

My code

```
val lista = listOf<Mood>(
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.blue, null), "Color1"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.purple, null), "Color2"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.green, null), "Color3"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.darkred, null), "Color4")
)

val adaptador = MoodArrayAdapter(this, lista)
spinner1.adapter = adaptador

spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object :
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        when (spinner1.selectedItem.toString()) {
            "Color1" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
            "Color2" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple)
            "Color3" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
            "Color4" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkred)
        }
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I want to create my spinner in this way

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-spinner-for-android-application) example for Kotlin. Pass a color using the data model as `backgroundColor` and assign the root layout an id as `rootLayout` in the item layout of the spinner used in the example then in the `createView()` of the `Adapter`, set passed color array's respective item to the `rootLayout` as `view.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(mood.backgroundColor)`. This is all you need, you can further customize the solution as you need, first implement it how I've told you, then you'll know what to do and how to do.

Comment: I have created a values ​​resource file called spinner, in the constraintlayout than this
create by default I have assigned ``android: id = "@ + id / rootLayout"
    android: background = "@ color / colorPrimaryDark" ``

finally in private fun createView ``(position: Int, recycledView: View ?, parent: ViewGroup): View``
I put this line of code ``view.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor (mood.backgroundColor)``
but I get red ``backgroundColor``

If I am wrong I apologize and ask for your great help

Comment: By default. you don't have to hardcode a color resource as you've done here : `android:background= "@color/colorPrimaryDark"`. You only have to set the color in the `CreateView()`. Next, how are you adding these values to the data class? Add the code, you might be passing only one color : Red. What you've to do is you've to pass a different color with every different value to get different colors. And add the code in the question and notify me through comment.

Comment: Share the code, because I think you're assigning the color to the spinner itself, instead of the item rows. Check the link again, you've to set the back ground color of each row's root layout which is shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/QAST5DI).

Comment: I have added my code, the rest of the code is the same as the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not shared the complete code though, but here's what you actually have to do.

1. Change the data model as :

   ```
   data class Mood(val backgroundColor: Color, 
       val description: String)
   ```
2. Change the item layout as (You don't need the `ImageView` though, you don't even need the `ConstraintLayout` though for a single `TextView` layout, but I'm keeping it for now) :

   ```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
       ...>
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/moodText"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
3. Change the `Adapter` class as :

   ```
   class MoodArrayAdapter(ctx: Context,
       moods: List<Mood>) :
       ArrayAdapter<Mood>(ctx, 0, moods) {
       override fun getView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
           return this.createView(position, recycledView, parent)
       }
       override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
           return this.createView(position, recycledView, parent)
       }
       private fun createView(position: Int, recycledView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
           val mood = getItem(position)
           val view = recycledView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
               R.layout.demo_spinner,
               parent,
               false
           )
           view.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(mood.backgroundColor)
           view.moodText.text = mood.description
           return view
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, set the adapter to the spinner as :

   ```
   moodSpinner.adapter = MoodArrayAdapter(
       this,
       listOf(
           Mood(Color.RED, "Angry"),
           Mood(Color.GRAY, "Happy"),
           Mood(Color.CYAN, "Playful"),
           Mood(Color.GREEN, "Wondering")
       )
   )
   ```

Now, you can change the variables/names where word "mood" is written as it suits you. Furthermore, I'm passing colors, you can use `Color.ValueOf(r,g,b)` for custom colors or you can change the `DataType` of `backgroundColor` in the data model to `int` and pass color resources from `colors.xml`.

**Edit ->** To access a color resource for this, pass it as :

```
From Activity -> Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.blue,null), "Angry")
From Fragment -> Mood(context.resources.getColor(R.color.blue,null), "Angry")
```

So, change your code accordingly as :

```
moodSpinner.adapter = MoodArrayAdapter(
    this,
    listOf(
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.blue,null), "Angry"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.red,null), "Happy"),
    Mood(Color.CYAN, "Playful"),
    Mood(Color.GREEN, "Wondering")
    )
)
```

Comment: It has worked for me, thank you very much, but I still have a question, I created in the
colors.xml
this color
<item name = "blue" type = "color"> # FF33B5E5 </item>
 <item> @ color / blue </item>

I try to call it in the MainActivity like this
 Mood (Color.blues, "Angry")
or in the Mood data class
val backgroundColor = (R.color.blues)
in both parts I get an error
 
Could you tell me how I should write and code to customize the colors

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo Check I've updated the answer to use color resources.

Comment: I have another question, wise teacher, how do I so that when selecting one of the rows a text view changes color, I have tried to do it as follows but I have not been able, I have updated the question.

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo For that, you've to use a [`onItemSelectedListener()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376648/8244632). In `onItemSelected()`, you can change the color of the `TextView` as `textView.setBackgroundColor(color)`. To change it according to the item selected, you can do `var selectedItem = (parent?.selectedItem as Mood)` then compare if the selected Mood value is the one for which you want to change color by `if(selectedItem.description.equals("YourChoice")` and if yes, then change the color of the TextView. This can be done in many ways.